# i have a controller redirect to a url I want that parameters should not be displayed as a query string

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

i am using

```
sendRedirect("http://api.mVaayoo.com/mvaayooapi/MessageCompose?user=someuser@gmail.com:123456&senderID=TEST SMS&receipientno=0987654321&dcs=0&msgtxt="+ message + "&state=4")
```

to call mvaayoo api for sendind sms .But the parameters are displayed in address bar to the client .
Is there a way to hide query string? I dont want to purchase SSL certificate.

Comment: are you using jsp or spring-mvc?

Comment: I am using Spring MVC

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not how you redirect, rather the problem is in the provider of the redirect URL you are trying to use:

http://api.mVaayoo.com/mvaayooapi/MessageCompose

No sensitive information should be used as a GET/query param.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to hide query string?

Pass additional data as *redirect attributes* instead of passing it as query parameters.

To carry data across a redirect use [`RedirectAttributes#addFlashAttribute(key, value)`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/support/RedirectAttributes.html#addFlashAttribute%28java.lang.Object%29).

What Java doc says:

> A RedirectAttributes model is empty when the method is called and is never used unless the method returns a redirect view name or a RedirectView.
>
> After the redirect, flash attributes are automatically added to the model of the controller that serves the target URL.

[Read more...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24668988/how-do-i-addobject-in-spring-redirectview)

Answer (score -1):

You need to use URLConnection to achieve this:

HTTP GET:

```
URLConnection connection = new URL(url + "?" + query).openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);
InputStream response = connection.getInputStream();
```

Target URL's doGet() method will be called and the parameters will be available by HttpServletRequest#getParameter().

HTTP POST:

```
URLConnection connection = new URL(url).openConnection();
connection.setDoOutput(true); // Triggers POST.
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=" + charset);

try (OutputStream output = connection.getOutputStream()) {
    output.write(query.getBytes(charset));
}

InputStream response = connection.getInputStream();
```

Target URL's doGet() method will be called and the parameters will be available by HttpServletRequest#getParameter().

Comment: It is a redirect request? You will get nothing using this.

Comment: Sorry, then you can put them in the session scope.

Comment: not even in session, that will also not work. A redirect request is a completely fresh session and request.

Comment: I see, the redirected URL is a different host, in a separated JVM.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look

```
    List<String> pathParam = null;
    if(null!=request.getPathInfo() && !request.getPathInfo().trim().isEmpty()){

        String paths[] = this.getPathInfo().replaceAll("\\/$|^\\/", "").split("/");
        pathParam = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(paths));
     }

    // assume your servlet url  is "/login/*" 

   // called url in browser /login/param1/param2/param3

    String param1 = pathParam.get(0);
    String param2 = pathParam.get(1);
    String param3= pathParam.get(2);
```

Comment: What are you trying to answer??

Comment: you can pass your parameter as url path not as query String

Comment: If you are redirecting third party url. It is not possible because all urls and parameters are controlled by that website

Comment: The question is about how to hide sensitive info from query params or in URL. Your answer does not address that at all.